# Can I call a function in a standalone google app script from a container-bound script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function in a container-bound google script.  I want to copy the function to a standalone script and have the function shared and called from different google sheets' scripts.  Is it possible?  Thanks for any guidance.

JD

I tried to copy the function in a container bound script to a standalone script.  I just do not know how to call this function from other container bound scripts.

Comment: Possibly with the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run).  I've never tried it but I think it might work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://support.google.com/docs/thread/166299351/call-a-function-from-another-project?hl=en